# Why does splice remove one number ahead of it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Kinda wierd but i have an array

var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];

and if i do array.splice(1);

it removes the 2 , 3 and the 4?

how do I remove only the 2 and leave both 3 and 4 as is?

so it would be var array = [ 1, 3, 4]; ?

Comment: Can you remove by name?

Comment: Welcome to the internet, feel free to use a website called google to find your way around. One of the first 1000000 entries when searching for 'javascript array splice' would've provided an answer in less than 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell splice how many elements to remove:

```
array.splice(1,1);  # start at index 1, remove 1
```

I am not sure if the form you used without that parameter is a standard, actually. It could be a browser-specific (Firefox/Spidermonkey) extension.

You can add even more parameters. Those will be elements to *replace* the removed elements with.

It's a versatile function, take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 0):

Function splice takes two or more arguments.
The first argument means the index of the first item to be removed.
The second argumemt means the number of items to be removed.
The third and after are data to replace removed items.

Your code lacks the second argument, so splice function removed all items after the index which is specified by first argument.

array.splice(1,1);

will remove only one item at index 1, so [1,2,3,4] becomes [1,3,4].